# Angular ngIf not displaying element when set to true

Tags: angular

I want to use an ngIf statement to render some HTML code after a certain period of time. Simplified for easier reproducibility, my HTML looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="reload===true">
  <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

and my Typescript, which sets the `reload` variable to `true` after two seconds, looks like this:

```
  reload: boolean;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reload = false;

    setTimeout(
      function() {
        this.reload = true;
        console.log(this.reload)
       }, 2000);
  }
```

Console logging `reload` indicates that this variable is being set to `true`. However, the code does not render in the view. Any ideas why?

Comment: Try using this syntax `<div *ngIf="reload">
  <p>Hello world</p>`
</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign this to new reference or use arrow function

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eanr3e-pwtjit?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

use arrow flat sintax(*):

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.reload = true;
  console.log(this.reload);
}, 2000);
```

(*)Arrow flat makes that "this" was the own Component

Comment: Changed as suggested, but it's not causing the problem. View still does not render code when the reload variable is set to "true."

Comment: Alex, a stackblitz with your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k4dsem?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Code suggested by @Eliseo should work fine. If it doesn't work then there's problem in your code, post full code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing this import

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

I was using the VS angular with core template which included several built in components. I tested this in all the other components' markups

```
<p *ngIf="true">fubar</p>
```

And it worked except for the one I added, which did not include this import, but after further digging I found that the import had been included in the parent component and was applied to it's children using the following code:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
NavMenuComponent,
HomeComponent,
CounterComponent,
FetchDataComponent...]}
```

So all I needed to do was add it to the NgModule declarations list. Including the import should work locally too. It seems the node compiler/interpreter doesn't catch missing imports.